# "flutter run" is not working on my phone after upgrading to android 13

Tags: flutter, android-13, run-app

When I run flutter apk on vs code it showing some error "**Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
Error launching application on I2012.**"

When I am running my app in vs code it will show some error after updating my phone to Android 13.

Comment: What is your targetSdk Version and CompileSdk version in `$project_root\android\app\build.gradle`. Edit your post to add these details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.